# Allure generating results for 2 test suites while running only one?

Tags: testng, allure

I am running a TestNG suite with 3 tests inside the same class. The problem is that when I open the Allure report (using jetty server), I can see 2 suites with the same name and same content inside. There are only 2 difference between each suite.

1. Suite 2 always finish 1 sec after Suite 1.
2. I am doing parallel execution on 3 devices using 3 different threads. if suite has thread order 1,2,3 then Suite 2 will have order 1,3,2 (compared to Suite 1)

The TestNG report looks fine. Can't find any suite duplication there.

Surefire config is given below.

---

Please find my surefire config below. Executor.xml is my testng xml.                 
                org.apache.maven.plugins
                maven-surefire-plugin
                2.12.2

```
            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
            <argLine>
                -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
            </argLine>
            <!--only for 1.3.* TestNG adapters. Since 1.4.0.RC4, the listener adds via ServiceLoader-->
            <properties>
                <property>
                    <name>listener</name>
                    <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener</value>
                </property>
            </properties>

                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>Executer.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Could you please specify your `maven-surefire-plugin` configuration?

Comment: Added the surefire config to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Since Allure 1.4.0.RC4, the listener adds via ServiceLoader*. To avoid result duplication please remove this part of your config.

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <name>listener</name>
        <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener</value>
    </property>
</properties>
```